# How to get NegotiateStream to use Kerberos?

Tags: authentication, negotiate

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474371/authenticating-windows-users-in-java-server), I've been trying to use NegotiateStream to authenticate a Windows client against a Java server.  It seems that Java doesn't have great NTLM library support, so I've been working on the assumption that I'd have to use Kerberos, which Java seems to support much better (via the GSS-API).

The problem is that NegotiateStream seems to be attempting to use NTLM every time.  The documentation suggests that it could use either, but doesn't specify how it chooses.  I can't see any options in the API to control which mechanism it chooses.  Is there a way?

I've got myself a Service Principal Name and my client code looks like this:

```
string spn = "<service-name>/<my-pc-name>"
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
NegotiateStream neg = new NegotiateStream(stream, true);
neg.AuthenticateAsClient(CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials, spn);
```

On the server end, the first set of bytes received are 22,1,0,0,59 and then "NTLMSSP" - which I wasn't expecting.

I've tried a few different formats for the SPN string, not sure what the correct format is there.  I originally created the SPN with

```
setspn -A <service-name>/<my-pc-name>.<domain-name> <my-user-name>
```

setspn -L lists it successfully as:

```
TEST/<my-pc-name>.<domain-name>
```

Am I doing something wrong, or completely misunderstanding this stuff? :)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Also, what are you using as myServicePrincipalName?

Comment: This is running on Vista64 right now.  I'm slightly confused about the proper format for myServicePrincipalName tbh - I've tried a few variants!  I created the SPN with this:

setspn -A TEST/<my-pc-name>.<domain-name> <my-user-name>

I'm not sure if that's right either! :S  It has registered the SPN, and I can look it up with

spn -L <my-user-name>

which lists

TEST/<my-pc-name>.<domain-name>

Given that, I was trying "TEST/my-pc-name", "TEST/my-user-name" and both of those with the domain name on the end as well.

Obviously a lot of guesswork going on, I haven't found great documentation :(

Comment: For completeness, I recommend to edit any details that you add into the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full syntax for an SPN name is `<service>/<user>@DOMAIN`; apparently, it is possible to omit the domain name. However, if the username is `my-pc-name.domain-name`, then you shouldn't shorten it further - provide the SPN exactly as `spn -L` lists it to you.

Comment: Ha, thanks - that works (only if I use the domain name).  So concretely, the string that works looks like this:

TEST/<my-pc-name>.<domain-name>@<domain-name>

I didn't think to try this combination as it looks so redundant, but I guess it makes sense.  It doesn't work without the @DOMAIN and the username seems to require the domain name within it too.

I'll update the question tomorrow morning to mention the SPN stuff.  Am I right in thinking then that NegotiateStream only uses Kerberos if a valid SPN is given, and just quietly falls back to NTLM if not?

Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: My guess is that it tries to acquire a ticket for the service from the KDC. If the KDC doesn't know the SPN, it won't issue a ticket, and then it falls back to NTLM (which doesn't actually need the "server name").